# Vue js resolve async modal

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise, vuejs3, vuetify.js

I would like to ask the user to enter a text in a vuetify modal before deleting something.

To open the modal, I just change the component prop "dialog" to true.
Once the modal is opened, the user will type his text and then click on the OK button.
When he clicks on it, the component property "dialog" is changed to false. The typed text is in a component prop called "details".

Why my promise is not resolved when the user clicks on OK?

```
async deleteItem() {
  const textResponse = await this.askText();
  ... another work to do here
},
async askText() {
  this.dialog = true;
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (this.dialog == false) {
      resolve(this.details);
    }
  });
},
```

Comment: The code inside your Promise is synchronous.  The if statement runs immediately, its result is false, and it never runs again, so the Promise is never resolved.  I'm not sure why this workflow should be asynchronous in the first place.  When clicking to delete, the event should open the modal.  Later, when the modal OK button is clicked, fire an event to run the delete function.  That can all be done with normal synchronous coding.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You are right, I could do this like you said and I will do it. But is there a solution to do it  with async way ?